# How to assign an object to a class property in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

Create a class called Vending Machine (VM) that returns an instance of a vending machine. The Vending Machine instance contains an inventory property which is an object that holds the name of inventory items and the total amount of stock of each item.

```
  drinkInventory = {
      1: { name: 'Sunny Delight', stock: 5 },
      2: { name: 'Diet Soda', stock: 3 },
      3: { name: 'Bottled Water', stock: 4 },
    };

class VM {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.iventory = Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to pass in drinkInventory

Comment: Why don't just let `this.inventory = obj`?

Comment: Tell your teacher to not abbreviate class names, variables. There's absolutely no reason to do it if you are not a robot.

Answer (score 0):

the more simple is `this.iventory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

```js
const drinkInventory= { 1: { name: 'Sunny Delight', stock: 5 }
                      , 2: { name: 'Diet Soda',     stock: 3 }
                      , 3: { name: 'Bottled Water', stock: 4 }
                      };

class VM {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.iventory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
  }
  getStock(key) { return this.iventory[key].stock }
}

let bob = new VM(drinkInventory);

drinkInventory['2'].stock = 50;

console.log( 'bob stock 2 =', bob.getStock(2) );
```

You can also use Spread syntax => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
const drinkInventory= { 1: { name: 'Sunny Delight', stock: 5 }
                      , 2: { name: 'Diet Soda',     stock: 3 }
                      , 3: { name: 'Bottled Water', stock: 4 }
                      };

class VM {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.iventory = { ...obj };
    // then repeat copy for first level of object entanglement
    for (let elm in obj )
      { this.iventory[elm] = { ...obj[elm] } } 
  }
  getStock(key) {
    return this.iventory[key].stock 
  }
}

let bob = new VM(drinkInventory);

drinkInventory['2'].stock = 50;

console.log( 'bob stock 2 =', bob.getStock(2) )
```